# React Redux - props.createMovie is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an issue with my first React/Redux project, it can be not so hard to solve it, but i'm confused. I think i did everything what was needed to work but seems like not.

So, I have HOC component **PopupWindow.jsx**

```
const PopupWindow = (WrappedComponent) => {

    return function (props) {
        const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
        const handleClose = (value) => {
            setShow(false);
            if (value) {
                props.createMovie(value);
            }
        }
        const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
        return (
                 <WrappedComponent show={show}
                                   handleClose={handleClose}
                                   handleShow={handleShow}
                                  {...props}/>)
    }
}

export default PopupWindow;
```

**Header.jsx**

```
const Header = ({handleShow, handleClose, show, createMovie}) => {
    return (
        <header className="img-blur-container header p-3">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <Logo/>
                    <Button
                        className="header_add-movie text-uppercase f-size-18 px-4 py-2"
                        onClick={handleShow}
                    >+ Add movie</Button>
                    <AddMovie show={show} handleClose={handleClose}/>
                </div>
                <Search/>
            </div>
        </header>
    )
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        createMovie: (movie) => dispatch(createMovie(movie))
    }
}


export default compose(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps),React.memo)(Header);
```

**AddMovie.jsx**

```
const AddMovie = ({show, handleClose}) => {
    const [movie] = movies;
    delete movie.id;



    return (
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} backdrop="static">
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Add movie</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <MovieForm/>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button type="reset" variant="outline-primary" size="lg">Reset</Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => handleClose(movie)} size="lg">Submit</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}
export default React.memo(AddMovie);
```

And I do warping like that:

```
const AddMovie = PopupWindow(Header)
```

In the result, when I'm trying to submit information about the movie, it gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: props.createMovie is not a function
    at handleClose (PopupWindow.jsx:35)
    at onClick (AddMovie.jsx:42)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299)
```

While in **Header.jsx** it is a function

```
props
createMovie: ƒ createMovie() {}
```

Action creators:

```
export const createMovieSuccess = (movie) => ({
    type: ACTIONS.CREATE_MOVIE_SUCCESS,
    payload: movie
});


export function createMovie(movie) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(MOVIES_API_PATH, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(movie),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }})
            .then((response) => response.json()
                .then((movie) => dispatch(createMovieSuccess(movie))))
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    data: null,
    totalAmount: 0
};

function moviesReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.CREATE_MOVIE_SUCCESS: {
            const movie = action.payload;
            return {
                ...state,
                totalAmount: ++state.totalAmount,
                data: [movie, ...state.data]
            }
        }
    default: return state;
    }
   }

export default moviesReducer;
```

What did I do wrong? Why?

Comment: AddMovie.jsx is a component that returns modal window of adding movie. I render it inside header
and const AddMovie = PopupWindow(Header)
is a component that returned from PopupWindow and it is a part of the page, I render it in other scope. Everything works except adding movie for some reason...

Comment: so what is addMovie ? you declared it twice. and, no.. createMovie will not be in the HOC.

Comment: What should I do for fixing it? Actually, I have no idea. Why createMovie won't be in the HOC?

Comment: a simple way to look at logic is, you passed handleShow, handleClose, show from PopupWindow to Header right? Then how Header pass createMovie to PopupWindow? Do you want to use createMovie in hoc or in the component?

Comment: a HOC should be simple and pure, with zero-side effects - https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#use-hocs-for-cross-cutting-concerns

Comment: I thought that createMovie will be passed to Header from the store, using mapDispatchToProps in the component, so I'll be able to pass it to AddMovie... So I need to re-write logic in the Hoc and then use connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PopupWindow)?

Comment: just put handleClose and handleShow inside your header component. You use redux because you don't want to pass function/state into nested child (e.g. Parent -> Child -> Child -> ) but you are now using HOC to pass function and state into nested child, defeating the purpose of redux.

Comment: If it is overly complicated, hard to debug, and causing more problems than convenience, then likely, those processes (e.g. HOC) are not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You connect the function `createMovie` just for `Header.jsx` file, by the function `mapDispatchToProps`. if you want to use `createMovie` also in the file `PopupWindow.jsx`- you need to connect again.

You have to add this code to the end of file  `PopupWindow.jsx`:
It will connect PopupWindow to redux store.

```
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            createMovie: (movie) => dispatch(createMovie(movie))
        }
    }
    
    
    export default compose(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps),React.

    memo)(PopupWindow);
```

then, you may send the function `createMovie` from `PopupWindow` to `Header`  by props, and cancel the connect in `Header`, but you may leave the `Header` code as it is.